# How do I make the driver navigate to new page in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, web-testing

I am trying to write a script to automate job applications on Linkedin using selenium and python.

The steps are simple:

1. open the LinkedIn page, enter id password and log in
2. open https://linkedin.com/jobs and enter the search keyword and location and click search(directly opening links like https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101452733&keywords=python&location=Australia get stuck as loading, probably due to lack of some post information from the previous page)
3. the click opens the job search page but this doesn't seem to update the driver as it still searches on the previous page.

```
    import selenium
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    import yaml
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
    
    url = "https://linkedin.com/"
    driver.get(url)
    content = driver.page_source
    stream = open("details.yaml", 'r')
    details = yaml.safe_load(stream)
    
    def login():
        username = driver.find_element_by_id("session_key")
        password = driver.find_element_by_id("session_password")
        username.send_keys(details["login_details"]["id"])
        password.send_keys(details["login_details"]["password"])
        driver.find_element_by_class_name("sign-in-form__submit-button").click()
    
    
    def get_experience():
        return "1%C22"
    
    login()
    
    jobs_url = f'https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/'
    driver.get(jobs_url)
    
    keyword = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'jobs-search-box-keyword-id-ember')]")
    location = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[starts-with(@id, 'jobs-search-box-location-id-ember')]")
    keyword.send_keys("python")
    location.send_keys("Australia")
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[normalize-space()='Search']").click()
    
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    
    # content = driver.page_source
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    # with open("a.html", 'w') as a:
    #     a.write(str(soup))
    
    print(driver.current_url)
```

*driver.current_url* returns https://linkedin.com/jobs/ instead of https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101452733&keywords=python&location=Australia as it should. I have tried to print the content to a file, it is indeed from the previous jobs page and not from the search page. I have also tried to search elements from page like experience and easy apply button but the search results in a not found error.

I am not sure why this isn't working.

Any ideas? Thanks in Advance

**UPDATE**

It works if try to directly open something like https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_AL=True&f_E=2&keywords=python&location=Australia but not https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?f_AL=True&f_E=1%2C2&keywords=python&location=Australia

the difference in both these links is that one of them takes only one value for experience level while the other one takes two values. This means it's probably not a post values issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting and printing the current URL immediately after clicking on the search button, before the page changed with the response received from the server.
This is why it outputs you with `https://linkedin.com/jobs/` instead of something like `https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?geoId=101452733&keywords=python&location=Australia`.
`WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` or `wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` will not cause any kind of delay like `time.sleep(10)` does.
`wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` only instantiates a `wait` object, instance of `WebDriverWait` module / class

Comment: I've tried time.sleep(10) that doesn't seem to be of much help

Comment: Do you mean you put ` time.sleep(10` instead of `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)` but `print(driver.current_url)` still presents you `https://linkedin.com/jobs/`?